# SQL query using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a database table called client_interests

It has the following fields:

client_id, min_price, max_price, property_type etc

The property_type field hold multiple values i.e.

property_type = Villa,House,Unit

At the moment, i use the following query to get all records for an ID.

```
public function getinterests($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('client_interests', array('client_id' => $id));
    return $query->row();
}
```

What i want to know is, how can i explode the property_interests in the controller and pass to my view?

In my controller i have this at the moment:

```
$data['client'] = $this->client_model->getinterests($id);
$this->layout->view('administration/clients/add_interests', $data);
```

and im displaying the values in the view like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="minrooms" value="<?php echo set_value('min_rooms', $client->min_rooms); ?>">
```

I basically want to populate the checkbox fields if they have been retrieved.

My checkboxes are shown like this:

```
 <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="house" name="propertytype[]">
            <?php echo $house; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="apartment" name="propertytype[]">
           <?php echo $apartment; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="unit" name="propertytype[]">
           <?php echo $unit; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="townhouse" name="propertytype[]">
           <?php echo $townhouse; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="villa" name="propertytype[]">
            <?php echo $villa; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="land" name="propertytype[]">
            <?php echo $land; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="acreage" name="propertytype[]">
            <?php echo $acreage; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="rural" name="propertytype[]">
            <?php echo $rural; ?></label>
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <input type="checkbox" value="block" name="propertytype[]">
            <?php echo $block; ?></label>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is really a bad structure you should store property types in another table with corresponding property id or if there are selected property types then store each type in individual columns

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode condition on `$client->property_type` to get each and every values in that colum . You can use `comma(,)` operator as the splitting criteria.